SMBIOS table not found ERROR: Failed to detect BIOS parameters when trying to boot VM qcow2 in qemu/kvm ubuntu 24.04 hypervisor
Error booting the VM from .qcow2 file on ubuntu 24.04 based hypervisor:
SMBIOS table not found
ERROR: Failed to detect BIOS parameters
while no problems on ubuntu 22,20 and Centos/Rhel/Rocky 7/8/9 based Linux hypervisors.
